# Maintaining REST with namespaced models in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, namespaces

I'm building an online store and thought it best to namespace the various composite parts. Products, Orders, Users etc...

I currently have the Product Module defined and laid out as follows

**Product::Base**
The underlying product itself it defines dimensions, a type and available colours

**Product::Type**
High level product categorisation

**Product::Colour**
HABTM colour relationship with Base

**Product::Unit**
Expands on base for varying quantities and shipping prices

Now my question relates to the controller and routing. I want the module to appear as the resource and have one of the models (base) as sort of the "head". I've managed to get this working with

```
  scope :module => "product" do
    resources :base, path: "product"
  end
```

which yields from rake routes

```
  base_index GET    /product(.:format)          product/base#index
           POST   /product(.:format)          product/base#create
  new_base GET    /product/new(.:format)      product/base#new
 edit_base GET    /product/:id/edit(.:format) product/base#edit
      base GET    /product/:id(.:format)      product/base#show
           PUT    /product/:id(.:format)      product/base#update
           DELETE /product/:id(.:format)      product/base#destroy
```

This is exactly the behaviour I want but my question is, **is this approach RESTful and correct?** I'd rather be told now I've got it wrong than further down the line.

Thanks as ever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is RESTful, yes, but try this too:

```
Blah::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :product do
    resource :base
  end  
end
```

Gives you:

```
     product_base POST   /product/base(.:format)      product/bases#create
 new_product_base GET    /product/base/new(.:format)  product/bases#new
edit_product_base GET    /product/base/edit(.:format) product/bases#edit
                  GET    /product/base(.:format)      product/bases#show
                  PUT    /product/base(.:format)      product/bases#update
                  DELETE /product/base(.:format)      product/bases#destroy
```

Comment: Thanks Captain V! I did have it working like this too but I wanted to keep the composite classes "under the hood" so to speak.

Comment: I think you're overcomplicating your classes. Basically, do NOT inherit controllers in this way, and maintain the 'modules' as separate models. Then build associations between those, OR aggregate them together in the Product Model.